# Changing the user password in first login

Tags: bash

I am using below script for create users, currently it is working, but I want to change the user password in their first login but unable to heddle that requirement with below script, i really want to fix the below script with password change asking when they first login

```
    useradd -p "${A_PASSWORD[$index]}" "${A_USERNAME[$index]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `useradd` manpage, there seems to be no option to do this directly. But you can use `passwd` or something like `chage -d0 [username]` to force a user to change the password after the first login.

Comment: thanks for the support